# get number of records on the basis of one value

Tags: sql

Input table

```
Col
1
2
3
4
5
```

Output

```
1
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
5
5
5
5
5
```

Is there any way this could be achieved in sql without writing any function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a self join approach:

```sql
SELECT t1.Col
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t2.Col <= t1.Col
ORDER BY t1.Col1;
```

The logic here is that each original `Col` value gets joined to however many records in the same table which its value represents.  If your actual data were not a perfect sequence, the above approach might still be viable, with some changes, with the help of analytic functions.

Comment: What if Col has duplicate values ? then ..?

Comment: You may run my answer using distinct selects against the table, to first remove duplicates.

Comment: but that wont solve the problem, lets say if I've 2 times 2, then in output should be 4 times 2....Isnt it ?

Comment: You should open a new question, as the one you asked above has been answered already.  You may cite this question if you wish.